# How to use feeder and value from session in Gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

How to use feeder and value from session for forming payload. Is this possible?

```
scenario("check")
.feed(ids)
.exec(http("check")
  .post("/check")
  .header("X-Token", session => session("token").as[String])
  .body(StringBody(session => 
    """
       |{
       |  "id": ${id},
       |  "subId": ${subId}
       |  "addressId": """" + session("token").as[String] + """"
       |}
    """.stripMargin
  ))
```

Comment: Do you have any problem with that code? One thing that does not look right is that you should surround token string with quotation marks. I'm also assuming that IDs are numerical so everything else looks fine.

Comment: @MateuszGruszczynski Yes. Thanks for pointing out. Corrected it.
Just wanted to know if it is possible to use session + feeder together. Looks like it's not.

Answer (score 1):

passing a session function into StringBody means that gatling expressions won't work. You can just pass in a string with embedded EL variables.

```
.body(StringBody("""
   |{
   |  "id": ${id},
   |  "subId": ${subId}
   |  "addressId": ${token}
   |}""".stripMargin
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments James. Just wanted to know if it is possible to use session + feeder together. Looks like it's not.

Comment: @James Warr do you know if is that some change in Gatling 3.0? I'm pretty sure that in 2.x EL expressions were evaluated after session expressions and it was possible to use both.

Comment: Not as far as i know. All the galling builders usually take an Expression[String] (where the EL tokens are automatically resolved) or a session function (where you have to use session("<varName>") )